# MYSQL Value error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with some values, like from 0 to 1 million. However if I want to select the highest value it does not work always, like it can have lower amount first and the big number as you can see on the image.

[image]

I have tried `SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY value DESC` but it does not give the highest value, also with ASC it does not give the lowest value first.

I really hope I can get help from here.

Comment: Is the `value` field an integer field or a varchar field? If it is a varchar field, does some of the values contain spaces and stuff?

Comment: What do you mean highest value? The most recent entry in the table or the row with some integer key being a maximum?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob i need all the values order by DESC not just one number.

Comment: Your code should be working, maybe you have something wrong somewhere

Comment: @KANAYOAUSTINKANE This is not the first time, like my Database would have numbers 4000 40 23 232 and i want them as DESC it sometimes can go  232 4000 23 40 and not DESC

Comment: **Plain text** is significantly more helpful than an illegible screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY length(value) DESC, value DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty clear from the attached image that the `value` field is ordered as string, not as number.

If the `value` field contains only integers (as shown on the embedded image), then change the data type of the column to one of the integer data types.

Otherwise, you can use the cast() function in the `order by` to convert the `value` field's contents to a number, however, if you have non-numeric values, then their values will be converted differently to numeric.

Comment: You can use a double order by clause, however, if the data stored within this field are actually numbers, then you have the wrong data type assigned to the field. A numeric data type requires less storage space and can be ordered more quickly. If the field can hold non-numeric values, then Syed Noman's answer can produce quite interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

`SELECT MAX(value) or SELECT MIN(value).`

If you just want the highest or lowest value.

Answer (score 0):

(Fewer reputations that's why posting as answer)

I have tested both cases `ASC` and `DESC` in my database

```
SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY value ASC
SELECT * FROM listings ORDER BY value DESC
```

It works perfectly can you explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

Cast to integer then order it:

```
SELECT * FROM listings 
ORDER BY CAST(`value` AS SIGNED) DESC
```